# Проблема с фрагментами

Tags: android, android-fragment

При натягивании фрагмента на активити, происходит ошибка

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private FrameLayout frame;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    frame = findViewById(R.id.frame);
    // Ошибка в new MapFragment()
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, new MapFragment(), "MapFragment").commit();
 }
}
```

Comment: У ошибки есть имя?

Answer (score 0):

У вас активити из support библиотеки, фрагмент оттуда же, скорее всего. Для него надо использовать фрагмент менеджер из библиотеки support, который можно получить методом getSupportFragmentManager()